# moveToElement(element,xoffset,yoffset) not working in selenium webdriver 2.32.0

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use `moveToElement(element,xoffset,yoffset)` of the Actions class in selenium web driver (java) in FireFox 21. but it seems it is not working. I have a extjs button control which acts as button as well as drop down(please refer screen shots).

### [image: extjs button cum drop down control]

When i click on the Save Changes section it saves the changes and when i am clickin on the drop down button attached to it, it opens up the list.
please refer the DOM source for the same control.

```
<td class="x-btn-mc"><em id="ext-gen514" class="x-btn-split" unselectable="on"><button id="btn-ext-comp-1739" class=" x-btn-text save-changes" type="button"><u>
      S
    </u>
      ave Changes
    </button></em></td>
```

Now i am able to click on the Save Changes button but i am not able to click on the drop down button by giving some offset position in the moveToElement method.

I have tried below two options:

1. `builder.moveToElement(element).moveByOffset(569,
   5).click().build().perform();`
2. `builder.moveToElement(element, 568, 5).click().build().perform();`

but both are not working.

The dimensions of the control are (117 x 16)

**Note:** do not get confused by offsets 568,5 as this offsets are still able to click on the save changes button.

Is it that this method is not yet supported in latest web driver?

Comment: Why don't you use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//text()='Resubmit'")).click();

Comment: @omkar to click on Resubmit i should be first able to click on drop down of Save changes button only then the Resubmit button will come into picture. Now i am able to click on the Save changes button, but i am somehow not able to click on the drop down control of the same control. Can you suggest something besides above code for the same.

Comment: can you paste the html code for drop down options

Comment: @Omkar drop down options will come later on into picture first i have to figure out on clicking the drop down button. and html code for drop down options is nothing but <li>. First i need to somehow click on the drop down button.

Comment: Where did you actually want to click as u are able to click on save change button will open the drop down options.

Comment: @Omkar: See if i click on the middle of Save Changes button then it will directly go and save, but if you will observe the button closely there is a small inverted triangle in the left hand side of the button(please see attached image). when u click on that triangle that list appears.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  Using `ClickAndHold()` and `Release()` worked when `Click()` did not.  I also like using percentages on any x,y coordinates so they are relative.  May or may not help you.  C# below.

```
        IWebElement MarkAs = MarkAsSpan(driver).FindElement(By.Id("btnMarkAs"));
        int Width = MarkAs.Size.Width;
        int Height = MarkAs.Size.Height;
        int MyX = (Width * 95) / 100;//spot to click is at 95% of the width
        int MyY = 1;//anywhere above Height/2 works
        Actions Actions = new Actions(driver);
        Actions.MoveToElement(MarkAs,MyX,MyY);
        Actions.ClickAndHold();
        Actions.Release();
        Actions.Perform();
```

Comment: The first line is showing up an error to me **'object doesnot contain a definition for 'FindElement' accepting first argument of type 'object' could be found

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem i solved by using below code may be this helpful for you,Try first find out the x and y offset.

```
    driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/toolbar/toolbars.html");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em")).click();   
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em")).getSize());
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//em")), 97, 16).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: i have used the same thing but it is not working. i guess the issue is with the method itself, it has not been implemented properly. any other workarounds to achieve that? which version of selenium and Firefox you were using can u share so that i can try porting to that version and try the same.

Comment: I am using Firefox 21.0 with Win 7.Have you get x and y offset using .get size method.

Comment: @Mrunal I am using Selenium Web-driver 2.32.0 version

Comment: yes the dimensions are : (117 X 16) i have tried following offsets : (117 X 16),(115 x 10),(110 x 5),(568 x 0),(568 x 10). all this offset combinations are directly clicking on the Save changes button and not on the inverted triangle to show the drop down list

Comment: Watch out for case sensitivity with names like findElement. In C# it is FindElement.

Answer (score 0):

Mrunal,

With the help of below code, you will be able to move your mouse in webdriver(java)

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement imageSpan = driver.findElement(By.className("badgeFeatured"));
actions.moveToElement(imageSpan);


WebElement subLink = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#headerMenu .subLink"));
actions.moveToElement(subLink);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Comment: i am using the same actions class. but my problem is i want to click on the drop down button of the Save Changes control which will show me the drop down list(containing control shown in the second image). for this i tried using moveToElement of the actions class but it is not working i guess. can u suggest some workaround for this

Comment: I have added few lines here again. check it now

Comment: i dont find element with class name as badgeFeatured neither a element with css as (#headerMenu .subLink). Any other workarounds?

Comment: please see above, the html code is there where we have <td><em><button> tags.